# How do I convert a `CString` into a `CHAR *`?

Tags: c++, c-strings

I have the following c++ code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <atlstr.h>

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    CString OFST_PATH;
    TCHAR DIR_PATH[MAX_PATH];

    GetCurrentDirectory(MAX_PATH, DIR_PATH);

    OFST_PATH.Format(DIR_PATH);

    CHAR *pOFST_PATH = (LPSTR)(LPCTSTR)OFST_PATH;

    return 0;
}
```

I want to understand why the value of `pOFST_PATH` in the end of the program is "c"?  what did `(LPSTR)(LPCTSTR)` casting of variable `OFST_PATH` did to the whole path that was written in there?

As you can see in the following window, when debuging the variables values are:

[image]

Comment: You will do yourself a favor by avoiding polluting one's mind with all these microsoftese-specific mutations like LPCSTR and Cstring, and such; and instead stick to C++ standard types like `char *` and `std::string`.

Comment: I agree with you completely but i have been restricted to use them only :/

Comment: That's unfortunate. In the past, facing an unacceptable job environment, I solved the problem by changing jobs. This kind of code makes my eyes bleed, and I fear long term brain damage.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`CString` and `LPCTSTR` are both based on `TCHAR`, which is `wchar_t` when `UNICODE` is defined (which it is, in your case, as I can tell by the value of `argv` in your debugger). When you do this:

```
(LPCTSTR)OFST_PATH
```

That works okay, because `CString` has a conversion operator to `LPCTSTR`. But with `UNICODE` defined, `LPCTSTR` is `LPCWSTR`, a.k.a. `wchar_t const*`. It points to an array of utf16 characters. The first character in that array is `L'c'` (that's the wide character version of `'c'`). The bytes of `L'c'` look like this in memory: `0x63 0x00`.  That's the ASCII code for the letter 'c', followed by a zero. So, when you convert your `CString` to `LPCTSTR`, that's valid, however, your next conversion:

```
(LPSTR)(LPCTSTR)OFST_PATH
```

That's not valid. `LPSTR` is `char*`, so you are treating a `wchar_t const*` as if it's a `char*`. Well your debugger assumes that when it sees a `char*`, it is looking at a null terminated narrow character string. And if you remember from above what the value of the bytes of the first character were, it is the ASCII value for the letter 'c', followed by a zero. So the debugger sees this as a null terminated string consisting of just the letter 'c'.

The moral of the story is, don't use c-style casts if you don't understand what they do, and whether they are appropriate.

Comment: Ah, I could not see the picture. To be fair, he didn't ask why it values looked scrambled. :)

Comment: Taking it one step further, don't EVER use c-style casts in C++.  Don't use C++ style casts if you don't understand what they do, particularly when using `reinterpret_cast<>`.